# JSoup: org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503, User-agent doesn't work

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to connect to a [site](http://www.patriarchia.ru/db/organizations/), fetch links from it, then visit each link in a `for` cycle and store some information from there. However I get a `org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=503` error when trying to access an inner site (inside `getAddress()` function). I tried setting timeout and changing user-agent, but it simply won't work. Accessing some of those sites individually does work though.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Parser {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String url="http://www.patriarchia.ru/db/organizations/";
        String homeUrl="http://www.patriarchia.ru";


        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36").get();
        Elements links = document.getElementsByClass("news");

        ArrayList<Company> companies=new ArrayList<Company>();
        int i=1;

        for (Element link : links) {
             Company companyCopy=new Company(link.text());

            Element title = link.getElementsByClass("title").get(0).getElementsByTag("a").get(0);
            String siteUrl=title.attr("href");

            companyCopy.setSite(homeUrl+siteUrl);


            getAddress(companyCopy.getSite());

            i++;
        }
    }

    public static String getAddress(String url)  throws IOException {
            Document document = Jsoup
                    .connect(url)
                    .ignoreContentType(true)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0").get();
            Elements dts = document.getElementsByClass("dt");
           Element dd;

        for (Element dt: dts)  {
               System.out.println(dt.text());
        }

        return "";
    }

}
```

I would really use some help here, because I have no idea what else to do. Changing timeout length also doesn't seem to help. I welcome any ideas and suggestions.

PS Nevermind the language, the links are on the main page, that's all that's important.

Comment: I've tried to run your code (well, part of it - getting the URL and extracting the `links` elemnts) and everything worked just fine - I got a list of 586 elements. I've used the same user agent that you did.

Comment: @TDG That's weird...